# Screen.width is bigger than 100% width

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, width

The image below shows 2 boxes when I scroll to the right end. I set the width of Box 1 to `100%`, and it fits the screen **perfectly**. However, when I set the width of Box 2 to `screen.width`, **the box's width is 100px bigger than the width of the screen.**

Could anyone please tell me why this happens? I need to do come calculation later on with Box 2's width, so I don't want to set the width to 100%.

Thank you in advance.

[image]

```
// Box 1
var svgStats = d3.select(position).append('svg').attr('width', '100%').attr('height', 300);

// Box 2
screenWidth = screen.width;
var svg_process_name = d3.select('#heatmap').append('svg').attr('margin-left', '20px').attr('width', screenWidth).attr('height', svgheight).attr("border", 1);
```

Comment: you'll need to show us some code otherwise there is not much we can do, but as a quick guess do you have padding on box 2 equal to 100px?  If so you may need to use box-sizing

Comment: You probably want `document.body.clientWidth` rather than `screen.width`.

Comment: Oh I see. Because of excluding padding. I set the width of `svg` element to the whole screen width.